# How to get typeof generic model's parameter inside of another type?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one interface which takes type T:

```
export interface ValueTimestampModel<T> {
    value: T;
    timestamp: string;
}
```

And I have a type which should use the above to transform a given model of type T by turning every parameter of T into `ValueTimestampModel`:

```
export type ModelWithTimestamp<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: ValueTimestampModel<typeof T[P]>
}
```

So the desired result would be -> if we have model:

```
{
   street: string;
   streetNo: number;
}
```

then `ModelWithTimestamp` version should be like:

```
{
   street: {
      value: string,
      timestamp: string
   },
   streetNo: {
      value: number,
      timestamp: string
   }
}
```

Unfortunately the part `typeof T[P]` returns the compilation error:

```
'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

It seems typescript wont accept `typeof` in this context. Are there any alternatives to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `typeof`, `T[P]` is already the type of property `P` in type `T`:

```
export interface ValueTimestampModel<T> {
    value: T;
    timestamp: string;
}


export type ModelWithTimestamp<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: ValueTimestampModel<T[P]>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgNUwBsBXYAFQQFtgBnGTKsAWQgBNgiAecgPjgDeAKDii4AN2JkAXHHIBuEWJjU6DJrPpRkAc0UBfIUdCRYcGAE8weVhyIB1BDAAWlGvUZge-ALyClogDaAAqISHAA1sAWEOhyALoA-LKEpBSqHky2nDwh8bxChkaW1nAAGnB+2Q5OrhnqXsJiWsDAMJow2kh6AS1tAHIQskgkVABGaAa8QA)